# How do I use custom fonts in Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I would like to use a font I've downloaded from the web for my project. It's stored as a .ttf file.

Could you please explain in in detail? Do I have to import it? If yes, where do I have to? And how do I tell Vuetify to use this font instead of the default one?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Web_fonts

Comment: how did you set up your project? is it a webpack project or are you using `vue-cli-3`?

Comment: I am using vue-cli-3

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using vue-cli-3 you can create a `sass` folder inside `src`, then add a `variables.scss` file in it, you can import a font in this file and set it as the value of the variable `$body-font-family`, something like this but with any font you want:

`@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap");
$body-font-family: "Roboto" !important;`

there is more information about it here: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/sass-variables

Comment: What do I do if there is no such variable as $body-font-family in my project? And where do I have to write the code you typed? In the newly created variables.scss?

Comment: you would need to add those 2 lines of code to `variables.scss`, but importing the font that you want to use instead of the one I included.